# Create a job in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, command, ssms, jobs

I would like to create a job in the Management studio. This job needs to check if there are "new" or  if there are "changes" in one table of access. This must run every 5 min.

If I create the job the next pop up will come.

[image: JOB command section]

What should I fill in the command section?

The check must come from this table "GRV_Audit_ChangesCreditorBankaccount"

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're trying to do -- send an email notifying of the insert/update, record details of the insert/update in another table or database, or even rollback or prevent the insert/update.

The possibilities are numerous.

You probably need to ask yourself (or your boss or whomever made the request): **What action do you want to take place when data in the target table(s) is updated or inserted?**

It may well turn out that a SQL Agent job isn't fit for purpose. You may end up looking at triggers or database auditing to achieve your goal.

Comment: Hi, I want to see if in a table a record has been changed, deleted or added. I am refuring to a table what consist of bankaccount numbers of creditors.

Comment: What are you comparing the data to? Once data in the table has been updated or inserted, it is the source of truth. If this is the only table containing those bank account numbers, you have no point of comparison, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could try investigating this as a possible solution...

1. Create an empty table with the same structure as your bank account numbers table.
2. Add an AFTER TRIGGER on your original table that additionally inserts data into your new table whenever the original table is updated

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Alternatively, if you are on SQL Server 2016 or greater, you could implement your bank account numbers table as a temporal table, which more or less does the same as the above automatically.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15